# OpenGL point array

Tags: arrays, opengl, vertex, voxel

I need to draw voxels using a float array like this:

```
{ v1.x, v1.y, v1.z, v1.size, v2.x, [...] }
```

which in my case, for testing purposes looks like this:

```
{ -0.6f, -0.4f, -0.0f, 1, 0.6f, -0.4f, -0.0f, 1, 0.f, 0.6f, -0.0f, 1, }
```

How do I load those up to the GPU and how do I then get the position and size values in the shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Buffer object of Vertices, then pass it to the GPU using specific APIs. In the shader, you can access data for each vertex. Take a look at the API glBufferData, for example in https://open.gl/drawing.

I am not sure if you would really need the Size/number of the vertices, but if you need it, you would need it to pass it as an uniform via glUniform1f.

Comment: Yes, thank you! The size, btw refers to the size of the individual voxels.

Comment: If it is a per-voxel size, then it would be passed as an "Attribute", just like the x,y,z itself.